# How to give warning if 80% of ram is used in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a program that gives me a warning if I used 80% of my ram. But I am not getting any response when I put the condition on the used memory percentage. Here is my program.

```
const os = require('os');


const CheckMemory = () =>{
    const total_memory = os.totalmem(); 
    const free_memory = os.freemem();
    const used_memory = total_memory - free_memory;
    const usedmemper = used_memory * 100 / total_memory; 
    return usedmemper.toFixed(2)+" %";
}


const Warning = (mem) =>{
    console.log(mem)
    if (mem <= 80 ) {
        console.log("You are currently using 80% of your available memory");
    }
} 


const Usedram = CheckMemory();
Warning(Usedram);
```

Answer (score 2):

The bug is that you are comparing strings with integers and JavaScript does not warn about that.

Let's say the memory is 99%. `CheckMemory` will return the string `99.00 %` in your example, which you will then compare against the integer 80:

```js
console.log("99.00 %" <= 80);
```

JavaScript will not complain, but return `false`. That is why you never see the warning printed.

To fix it, `CheckMemory` should return a number (between 0 and 100), not a human readable string (like `80.23 %`).